# using httr to connect to API with pem certificate

Tags: r, rcurl, httr

I've successfully connected to a public app I created using this syntax:

```
library(httr)
public_app <- oauth_app("website_public",
               key    = "BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH",
               secret = "ADIFFERENTBLAHBLAH")
website_token_public <- oauth1.0_token(oauth_endpoint(authorize = 'https://api.website.com/oauth/Authorize',request = 'https://api.website.com/oauth/RequestToken',access = 'https://api.website.com/oauth/AccessToken'),public_app)
req=GET("https://api.website.com/api/stuff/uniquestring",config(token=website_token_public))
```

but, being a public app, it expires so I'm attempting to use a private app based on a X509 certificate.
I've successfully created the *.cer certificate and uploaded it the to website app.
I'm now trying, and failing, to connect to it via R.
My (albeit limited) understand is that a private key doesn't require the token, which to me renders the oauth1.0_token bit redundant.  But if that is the case, how/where do I specify my key and secret.
So far I've got:

```
private_app <- oauth_app("website_private",key = "SOMEMOREBLAH",secret = "FURTHERBLAH")
req <- GET("https://api.website.com/api/stuff/uniquestring", config(cainfo='/filepath/websitekey.pem'))
```

but I can't figure out whether I need to put the key & secret into the GET-config() -and if so, where?  Or do I still need to specify a oauth1.0_token?  I have tried various iterations along the lines of:

```
website_token_private <- oauth1.0_token(oauth_endpoint(request = NULL,authorize = NULL, access = 'https://api.website.com/oauth/AccessToken'), app=private_app)
```

all advice extremely appreciated!

thanks.